# Using pardiso solver with eigen

Tags: c++, algorithm, g++, eigen, pardiso

I'm trying to solve very large `sparse matrix system (Ax = b)` with `eigen` using `pardiso` solver. 
When I compile the code with `g++`, This error comes out:

```
In file included from ${Eigenroot}/Eigen/PardisoSupport:31,
                 from code.cpp:8:
${Eigenroot}/Eigen/src/PardisoSupport/PardisoSupport.h: In static member function 'static IndexType Eigen::internal::pardiso_run_selector<IndexType>::run(void*, IndexType, IndexType, IndexType, IndexType, IndexType, void*, IndexType*, IndexType*, IndexType*, IndexType, IndexType*, IndexType, void*, void*) [with IndexType = int]':
${Eigenroot}/Eigen/src/PardisoSupport/PardisoSupport.h:269:   instantiated from 'Derived& Eigen::PardisoImpl<Derived>::compute(const typename Eigen::internal::pardiso_traits<Derived>::MatrixType&) [with Derived = Eigen::PardisoLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int> >]'
${Eigenroot}/Eigen/src/PardisoSupport/PardisoSupport.h:409:   instantiated from 'Eigen::PardisoLU<_MatrixType>::PardisoLU(const MatrixType&) [with MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>]'
code.cpp:82:   instantiated from here
${Eigenroot}/Eigen/src/PardisoSupport/PardisoSupport.h:50: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'const long long int*' for argument '2' to 'void pardiso(void*, const long long int*, const long long int*, const long long int*, const long long int*, const long long int*, const void*, const long long int*, const long long int*, long long int*, const long long int*, long long int*, const long long int*, void*, void*, long long int*)'
```

I thought that I don't need to change the `sparse matrices`' form but it seems like I need to change the sparse matrix form should fit into `pardiso`.
But when I found other's sample code, they didn't change `sparse matrix` form.
And it seems work too.

Am I getting it right? I'm not so sure. 
Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

(About the A and B they aren't related to this problem. Cause I did get the answer with sparseLU which is built-in solver from eigen. But the speed of it was too slow, I try to use pardisoLU.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>
#include <Eigen/PardisoSupport>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat;

int main(){ 
int m = 10000; // number of rows;
int n = 10000; // number of cols;
SpMat A(m,n); // declare sparse matrix A
//
make tripletlist
//
A.setFromTriplets(TripletList.begin(), TripletList.end());
SpMat B(m,1);
// 
insert values into B
//
PardisoLU< SparseMatrix<double> > solver( A );
x = solver.solve( B );
}
```

And compile this with `g++` as

```
g++ -I ${Eigenroot} -DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL -DMKL_ILP64 -m64 -I ${mklroot}/linux/mkl/include -o out.out code.cpp -L ${mklroot}/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 -Wl, -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64 -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Comment: Where did you declare `B` and `x`? Or `TripletList`? Make sure that the code you post represents your problem (don't leave out important parts). Read how to produce a [mre].

Comment: Actually tripletlist , B and x are not related to this problem so I didn't include those parts.

Answer (score 1):

probably some problems happen with ILP64 linking. Could you try to link without -DMKL_ILP64 option and with -lmkl_intel_lp64 instead of -lmkl_intel_**ilp64**?

Comment: I tried
//
g++ -I ${Eigenroot} -DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL -m64 -I ${mklroot}/linux/mkl/include out.out code.cpp -L ${mklroot}/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 -Wl, -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64 -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl
//

But also got these errors..

/usr/bin/ld: : No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status